# Javascript menu hover action: wont stop cascading

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menubar, cascadingdropdown

Here is the website I am talking about: http://benjaminpotter.org/clients/c3carlingford/

---

So I am building a menu that has popups appear when you hover over a menu item:

[image]

and so I have written a javascript (jQuery) function to animate it:

```
$(".info").css({"opacity": "0", "margin-top": "10px"}).hide(0);

$("#menu-item-51").mouseenter(function(){

    $(".nav1").stop(0).show(0).delay(300).animate({"opacity": "1", "margin-top": "-3px"}, {"duration": (250)});

});

$("#menu-item-51").mouseleave(function(){

    $(".nav1").stop(0).show(0).delay(0).animate({"opacity": "0", "margin-top": "10px"}, {"duration": (150)});

});

$("#menu-item-11").mouseenter(function(){

    $(".nav2").stop(0).show(0).delay(300).animate({"opacity": "1", "margin-top": "-3px"}, {"duration": (250)});

});

$("#menu-item-11").mouseleave(function(){

    $(".nav2").stop(0).show(0).delay(0).animate({"opacity": "0", "margin-top": "10px"}, {"duration": (150)});

});

$("#menu-item-12").mouseenter(function(){

    $(".nav3").stop(0).show(0).delay(300).animate({"opacity": "1", "margin-top": "-3px"}, {"duration": (250)});

});

$("#menu-item-12").mouseleave(function(){

    $(".nav3").stop(0).show(0).delay(0).animate({"opacity": "0", "margin-top": "10px"}, {"duration": (150)});

});

$("#menu-item-13").mouseenter(function(){

    $(".nav4").stop(0).show(0).delay(300).animate({"opacity": "1", "margin-top": "-3px"}, {"duration": (250)});

});

$("#menu-item-13").mouseleave(function(){

    $(".nav4").stop(0).show(0).delay(0).animate({"opacity": "0", "margin-top": "10px"}, {"duration": (150)});

});

$("#menu-item-14").mouseenter(function(){

    $(".nav5").stop(0).show(0).delay(300).animate({"opacity": "1", "margin-top": "-3px"}, {"duration": (250)});

});

$("#menu-item-14").mouseleave(function(){

    $(".nav5").stop(0).show(0).delay(0).animate({"opacity": "0", "margin-top": "10px"}, {"duration": (150)});

});

$("#menu-item-15").mouseenter(function(){

    $(".nav6").stop(0).show(0).delay(300).animate({"opacity": "1", "margin-top": "-3px"}, {"duration": (250)});

});

$("#menu-item-15").mouseleave(function(){

    $(".nav6").stop(0).show(0).delay(0).animate({"opacity": "0", "margin-top": "10px"}, {"duration": (150)});

});
```

so firstly there is the issue that it is a lot of code... but it works...

### So what's the issue?

The issue is this:

[image]

when you mouse back and fourth over all the links, it cascades. Cool I know, but the client doesn't like it. Neither do I.

So how do I change it so that it behaves better?

I would love it to work like this:

[image]

where their dropdowns don't have the same: mouse over all, cascade thing...

You can check out their site here: http://thecity.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `stop(0)` to `stop(true, true)` at all the places in your code. It should work as expected.

Passing `true` as both the arguments to `stop` method makes sure it clears the queue of previous animations and also forcefully completes them quickly if they are still animating.

`stop(clearQueue, jumpToEnd)` - Stops the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

On your `mouseleave` event I would use the `.hide()` method from jQuery.
I'm just assuming that you would like to hide the elements after leaving the menuitem?

I made a quick fiddle to illustrate the problem. [Click here for results](http://jsfiddle.net/KnaUU/1/)

Good luck!